# Chatter issues to resolve

Tags: chatter, search, global-search

I have below two requirements regarding Chatter.

1. I need the Quick find search box to be shown at left side as it shows when chatter disabled.
2. Stop the emails to the user when the followers are added or anyone in the followers posted.

I have chatter enabled in my org. How can I implement these requirements?

Please note I do manage chatter through permission set.

By Quick Find search box, I mean the default search box I mean the highlighted box in attachment.[image]

Answer (score 2):

To stop emails for each user in their settings under chatter you can change the email notifications for that user. I'm not sure what you mean by the Quick Find Search box. Can you explain that requirement a little more?

Comment: By Quick Find search box, I mean the default search box I mean the highlighted box in attachment.

Comment: How can I change Email notifications for all Chatter Users at one go using data load?

Comment: Where do you want to add the global search to chatter? I'm still confused where you want to add the global search. It should be at the top of every standard salesforce page. For the data load to update chatter notification emails please review this article that I found: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193182&type=1